# nextjs empty link throws multiple children error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to use a `<Link />` with no content inside of it within my app. But, for whatever reason, if I *don't* pass any content to it I get the [multiple children error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children) – when, in fact, quite the opposite is occurring.

So, how would I get the following code to work without doing any funky workarounds? The documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about it.

```
<Link href="/example"></Link>
```

Comment: Either use an `<a>` tag instead of `<Link>`, or you can add a React fragment inside, which will not add extra HTML.

Comment: It depends how you define "funky workarounds".

Comment: `next/link` will not render an `<a>` tag if not passed one as a child. Although not mentioned directly, all the [examples in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) have an `<a>`.

Comment: What are you passing to it exactly?

Comment: @juliomalves nothing. See the question.

Comment: @juliomalves I haven't worked with Next for a while, so I forgot, but yes, I can confirm you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) can solve the problem; they don't add extra HTML elements. You could do something like this (make sure to import React):

```
<Link href="/example">
  <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
</Link>
```

Or simply:

```
<Link href="/example"><></></Link>
```

This way you're passing exactly "one child" to `<Link>` that returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an anchor element as children and `passHref` as prop of the `Link` element.

```
<Link href="/example" passHref>
  <a />
</Link>
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref